# Is it possible to display specific screen during Android screenshot?

Tags: android

I want to prevent users from being able to take a screenshot of my application.

I know you can do the following

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

But I would rather blur the current screen background and display an elegant "no pictures allowed" message.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can try to detect a combination of physical button presses, the most common one is power+volume down, and then blur the screen. But I think it will not be 100% secure